# Dict-like object with no __getitem__, __setitem__

Tags: python, twisted, gdbm

If you do

```
import gdbm
db = gdbm.open('foo', 'cs')
```

You get an object which is:

```
<gdbm.gdbm at 0x7f0982b9aef0>
```

You can now set keys and values in the database via:

```
db['foo'] = 'bar'
print db['foo']
```

I wanted to use these from Twisted and make a wrapper for `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` which returns deferreds.  However, I noticed something peculiar:

```
In [42]: dir(db)
Out[42]: ['close', 'firstkey', 'has_key', 'keys', 'nextkey', 'reorganize', 'sync']
```

This object hasn't got `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.  Trying either of these gives an attribute access error.  Yet, it behaves like a dictionary.  What sort of object is this?

(I suspect this is a C extension object, but I find it odd that it has dict-like access methods, but no `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.  A pointer to Python doc describing this behavior would be helpful.)

Further: how would you get references to `db.__getitem__` and `db.__setitem__` if you wanted to wrap them in a deferred?  The only solution I see is to wrap db in a utility class:

```
class Db:
    def __init__(self, db):
         self.db = db

    def __getitem__(self, x):
         return self.db[x]

    ...
```

But perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Comment: What do you mean "wrap them in a deferred"?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: I meant writing something of the spirit `class Db: def get(self, key): return deferToThread(db.__getitem__, key)`.  Performance isn't an issue here, but I would be very interested to know what you think of accessing gdbm from Twisted in that manner.

Comment: In my experience, turning syntactic constructs like `db[key]` into implicitly threaded (or otherwise complicated, long-running) operations leads to more confusion than it's ultimately worth.  Also, keep in mind that `__setitem__` isn't even allowed to return a value - so the `Deferred` representing the completion of that operation in a thread is lost (so, for example, you have no way to do error handling).

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: thanks. Yes, explicit is better, I have it written now as `d = db.set(key, value)` and `d = db.get(key)`. It works very nicely and looks decent in `inlineCallback`-ed functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdbm` is indeed a C module; the object implements the C-API [mapping protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#mapping-object-structures) instead.

See the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9524e1468913/Modules/gdbmmodule.c#l215) for the `PyMappingMethods` structure with function pointers.

You could use [`operator.getitem()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) to access the keys:

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> db['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> getitem(db, 'foo')
'bar'
```

You could wrap `getitem()` in [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make it an efficient callable with one argument:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> gi = partial(getitem, db)
>>> gi('foo')
'bar'
```

As `getitem` and `partial` are implemented in C, this combo will always be faster than custom objects, functions or lambdas to wrap the access.